# Create sub directory in data bricks using java / spring boot

Tags: java, azure, databricks

Currently we are working on a requirement, where we need to create sub directories in azure data bricks using java.

From Databricks UI, we are able to create subdirectory. Whether we can create subdirectory from Java code.

[folders created from databricks UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzmJh.png)
[file inside created folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZTnA.png)

Using curl command, we are able to create subdirectory from terminal. But, when we use ProcessBuilder in Java code it is not creating subdirectory.

Curl command for reference :

curl -n -X POST -H 'Authorization: Bearer ***' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{ "path":"/Users/*.com/testfolder4" }' https://***.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/workspace/mkdirs

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In azure databricks, we are opening python file that we store in file storage. Now, we want those python files to be maintained in different sub directories and open the python file from those directories. For that, we need to create sub directories in azure databricks.